# Interpretation of MATLAB's NaiveBayses 'posterior' function

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, naive-bayes

After we created a Naive Bayes classifier object `nb` (say, with multivariate multinomial (`mvmn`) distribution), we can call `posterior` function on testing data using `nb` object. This function has 3 output parameters:

> [post,cpre,logp] = posterior(nb,test)

I understand how `post` is computed and the meaning of that, also `cpre` is the predicted class, based on the maximum over posterior probabilities for each class.

The question is about `logp`. It is clear how it is computed (logarithm of the PDF of each pattern in `test`), but I don't understand the meaning of this measure and how it can be used in the context of Naive Bayes procedure. Any light on this is very much appreciated.

Thanks.